# Why the expected output starts with 0 and not 1 on this code challenge?

Tags: javascript, conways-game-of-life

> #### Game of Life Strings
>
> The universe of the Game of Life is an infinite two-dimensional orthogonal grid of square cells, each of
> which is in one of two possible states, alive or dead. Every cell
> interacts with its eight neighbours, which are the cells that are
> horizontally, vertically, or diagonally adjacent. At each step in
> time, the following transitions occur:
>
> - Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
> - Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
> - Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.
> - Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
>
> Implement the method that calculates new generation of game of life.
> The method receives a string in the format "000_000_000" that
> represents the matrix NxM of 0's (dead cell) and 1's (living cell).
>
> And returns a string in the same format "000_000_000" that represents
> equally sized array representing the next generation. Cells outside
> the array must be considered dead. Cells that would born out of the
> array boundaries should be ignored (universe never grows beyond the
> initial NxM grid).
>
> ##### Examples
>
> - Input: `"000_111_000"`
> - Output: `"010_010_010"`

PS. I am not asking for any implementation just help to understand this. Once I understand the implementation is just a detail.

Comment: Why would you expect the first digit, the corner of the 3x3 square, _not_ to be 0? That cell was dead to begin with and has only two live neighbours.

Comment: Because there are 3 neighbors alive, not 2 it should become 1 like the second digit. No? What did I miss?

Comment: _"there are 3 neighbors alive"_ - no, there aren't. _"Cells outside the array must be considered dead"_ and it only has three neighbours inside: two living, one dead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you. I think that I got it. I was mounting it in my head like this [[0,0,0],[1,1,1], [0,0,0]. Then as I understand now a string "111_111_111" will become "101_000_101"

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow the rules.

The string represents a 2D grid

```
"000_111_000"
```

is

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0 / dead | 0 / dead | 0 / dead |
| **2** | 1 / live | 1 / live | 1 / live |
| **3** | 0 / dead | 0 / dead | 0 / dead |

(added coordinates for clarity: A1 is top-left with value `0`/dead and B2 is in the middle with value `1`)

Going down the list of rules and each cell:

- **A1 (dead)** has *three* neighbours: B1 (dead), B2 (live), A2 (live)

  - no rule applies, the value `0` remains
- **A2 (live)** has *five* neighbours: A1 (dead), B1 (dead), B2 (live), B3 (dead), A3 (dead)

  - First rule applies: fewer than two live neighbours, therefore the value changes to `0`
- **A3 (dead)** has *three* neighbours: A2 (live), B2 (live), B3 (dead)

  - no rule applies, the value `0` remains
- **B1 (dead)** has *five* neighbours: C1 (dead), C2 (live), B2 (live), A2 (live), A1 (dead)

  - Fourth rule applies: exactly three live neighbours, therefore the value changes to `1`
- **B2 (live)** has *eight* neighbours: B1 (dead), C1 (dead), C2 (live), C3 (dead), B3 (dead), A3 (dead), A2 (live), A1 (dead)

  - Second rule applies: two live neighbours, therefore the value changes remains `1`
- **B3 (dead)** has *five* neighbours: B2 (live), C2 (live), C3 (dead), A3 (dead), A2 (live)

  - Fourth rule applies: exactly three live neighbours, therefore the value changes to `1`
- **C1 (dead)** has *three* neighbours: C2 (live), B2 (live), B1 (dead)

  - no rule applies, the value `0` remains
- **C2 (live)** has *five* neighbours: C1 (dead), C3 (dead), B3 (dead), B2 (live), B1 (dead)

  - First rule applies: fewer than two live neighbours, therefore the value changes to `0`
- **C3 (dead)** has *three* neighbours: C2 (live), B3 (dead), B2 (live)

  - no rule applies, the value `0` remains

This results in

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0 / dead | 1 / live | 0 / dead |
| **2** | 0 / dead | 1 / live | 0 / dead |
| **3** | 0 / dead | 1 / live | 0 / dead |

Which in turn when encoded back to a string matches the putput

```
"010_010_010"
```

Answer (score 0):

After the help here to understand it, this is one possible solution using javascript

```
const getNewString = (str) => {
    const cells = str.replace(/_/ig, '').split('').map(num => parseInt(num));
    
    const result = []

    // Considering a 3x3 matrix
    for(let cellIndex=0; cellIndex < cells.length; cellIndex++){
      
       const position = Math.floor((cellIndex/3) % 1 * 100);
       const isFirst = position === 0
       const isLast = position === 66
       
       if(cellIndex > 2 && isFirst){
         result.push('_')
       }

      let sum = 0
      
      const backBreakIndex = isFirst ? 3 : 4

      for(let back = cellIndex-1; back >= cellIndex-backBreakIndex; back--){
        const isNeighbour = ((!isFirst && (back < cellIndex-1)) || (!isLast && (back!==cellIndex-2)))
        
        if(cells[back] && isNeighbour){
          sum++
        }
      }
      
      const forwardBreakIndex = cellIndex + (isLast ? 3 : 4)
  
      for(let forward= cellIndex+1; forward <= forwardBreakIndex; forward++){
        const isNeighbour = (!isLast && forward!==cellIndex+1 ) || (!isFirst && forward!==cellIndex+2)
        
        if(cells[forward] && isNeighbour){
          sum++
        }
      }

      if(cells[cellIndex]){ // is alive
         result.push(sum > 1 && sum < 4 ? 1 : 0); 
      }else{
        result.push(sum === 3 ? 1 : 0); 
      }

    }
    return result.join('')
}
 console.log(getNewString('000_111_000'))
 console.log(getNewString('000_000_000'))
 console.log(getNewString('111_111_111'))
 console.log(getNewString('11'))
```